# How do you link up checkbox to model in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

Take the following **model**:

```
ProductItems = [
    {
        ID: "",
        Image: "",
        Selected: null
    }
]
```

**view:**

```
                <tr ng-repeat="item in ProductItems">
                    <td><input 
                            ng-model="item.Selected"
                            type="checkbox" value="<% item.ID %>" /></td>
                    <td><img width="50" src="<% item.Image %>" /></td>
                    <td><% item.Name %></td>
                </tr>
```

**and controller:**

```
$scope.$watch( "item.Selected" , function( newVal ){
    alert( "hi" );
    productsSelected.push( newVal );
}, true );
```

why is this not working? It doesn't seem to reach the alert when i check a checkbox
I'm not sure i understand how the binding and watching works?

The context is I want to keep track of all ticked items in a pginated table then submit a form server side with this info.

Comment: try watching `ProductItems` instead, the `item in ProductItems` creates the item object only within the scope of the `ng-repeat` loop

Comment: Thanks LcLK... It works, i'm being an idiidot.. thankyou!

Comment: And an alternative to consider: You are watching an object which is changed through a checkbox. The checkbox gives you an `on-change` attr which can be given a callback function similar to the regular `on-click` attr. Use that rather than watching the collection of objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with an inner controller like:

```
<div data-ng-controller="MainController">
    <table>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in items" data-ng-controller="InnerController">
            <td><input ng-model="item" type="checkbox" />{{item}}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div> 
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('MainController',function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]; 
})
.controller('InnerController',function($scope) {
    $scope.$watch( "item" , function( newVal, oldVal ){
        console.log( newVal, oldVal );
    });
});
```

Comment: Is thee a way that the $watch can tell you which item was modified? Or do i need to apply a ng-change for that?

Comment: Now the snippet when click on a checkbox the newVal is true

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type=checkbox ng-model=myCollection.property>
{{myCollection.property}} <!-- shows true or false -->
```

Comment: Could you add a rational for your answer? Otherwise your answer might get deleted.

Comment: Who would delete my answer? It is the most correct one.

Comment: We are not arguing the validity of the answer, but we are asking you to explain why this code solve the issue